# Parent Div not adjusting size due to its child div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to load my HTML page into a container. However, when I try to load the HTML page, the container doesn't re-adjust its size to accommodate the Page. The contents of my page are still visible but they look like they are overflowing without the background of the container. I am new to WebDev and have no idea about this.

I have three containers. Container Big holds other two containers. ContainerMain holds navigation bar in it and I load page into containerPage whenever someone clicks the nav bar. I want containerMain and ContainerPage to look like a scrollable continous box at the center of container Big with some top and bottom margins but, whenever I load the page into containerPage, it fails to resize itself for the page (in this case, homepage).

```
<div id="ContainerBig">
    <div id="ContainerMain"></div>
    <div id="containerPage"></div>
</div>
```

Here is css for my containers:

```css
#ContainerBig {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#ContainerMain {
    top:10%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    max-height: 77px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #262523;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
#containerPage {
    top: min(20%,160px);
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

And I'm trying to load the following webpage:

```js
// Just in case you need it, the code I'm using to load the page is:

function changePage(page, context) {

    $(".navItem").removeClass("active");
    $(context).addClass("active");

    var contain = $("#containerPage");
    contain.slideUp("10ms", "linear", function change() {
        contain.load(page);
        contain.slideDown("10ms");
    });

    if ($(window).width() < 1126) {
        var element = document.getElementById("nav");
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 13px;

}

#vertical_line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 69%;
    bottom: 12%;
    top: 12%;
    border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.pic_owner {
    top: 15%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border: white 10px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.description_owner {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 34%;
    width: 33%;
    line-height: 21px;
}

#more {
    display: block;

    font-weight: 400;
}

#heading {
    color: #333;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.social {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 72%;
    right: 6%;
    line-height: 21px;

}

.socialButton {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    top: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 6%;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fa:hover {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.fa-instagram {
    background: #E1306C;
}

.fa-linkedin {
    background: #007bb5;
}

.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
}

.fa-github {
    background: #141414;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleSheets/styleHomePage.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/homepage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <img class="pic_owner" src="Resources/picture_aayush.jpg">

        </img>

        <div class="description_owner">
            <h1 id="heading">DEVELOPER</h1>
            <p><strong id="desc_detail">Loading.....</strong></p>
            <p id="more">Loading....</p>
        </div>

        <span id="vertical_line"></span>

        <div class="social">
            <p id="addition"></p>
            <a href="" class="socialButton fa fa-github" type="button">&nbsp</a>
            <a href="" class="socialButton fa fa-linkedin"
               type="button">&nbsp Aayush Singla</a>
            <a href="h" class="socialButton fa fa-facebook" type="button">&nbsp </a>
            <a href="" class="socialButton fa fa-instagram" type="button"></a>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please bare with me if this is a simple question. I am stuck on this from kinda week now.
[image: screenshot of my page]

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн I added a picture of the issue. couldn't get jsfiddle to work.

Answer (score 1):

update:

It looks to me like if you want both the header and the page content to scroll together, you need a container element with `overflow: auto` on it.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="ContainerBig">
  <div id="Container">
    <div id="ContainerMain"></div>
    <div id="containerPage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//CSS
#ContainerBig {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#Container {
  position: absolute;
  top:10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#ContainerMain {
    height: 10%;
    max-height: 77px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #262523;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
#containerPage {
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/jacob_124/pen/ZEQoBxE?editors=1100

**Note: It's a bad idea to rely on position absolute for layouts. Especially for when you don't have to. This layout could be easily accomplished with relative positioning.**
Here's a pen with position relative: https://codepen.io/jacob_124/pen/BajxQbv

Comment: Removing height 100% doesn't change anything. I want both containers, containerMain and containerPage to scroll down, that is containerBig should have scrolling enabled. Rest two containers should just show their complete contents. But, the problem here is that when I load a page into containerPage, it somehows calculates the total height to be 0, which shouldn't be the case, as everything I am loading has its height. In the picture, that white part should extend down to show the whole homepage. I hope this clears everything.

Comment: Looks to me like you need an extra container that will scroll. I made this Pen to explain what I mean: https://codepen.io/jacob_124/pen/ZEQoBxE?editors=1100

Comment: I was able to do what you designed. Please check out aayushsingla.github.io . When you will kick on About Me, that's the behaviour I'm expecting. And when you will click on Home, that's what the problem is. The overflow thing.

Comment: The only back that it doesn't work on is the Resume page where the load in an iFrame.

Comment: The text overflows for me out of the contentPage, in home. I'm using chrome on desktop. In About Me, the page extends itself for the content.

Comment: It looks fine for me. I'm using windows as well. I don't know if that changes anything